# Show Previous select object blue and current red

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () 
{               
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray Raycost = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit Hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(Raycost , out Hit , 230.0f , mask_ ))
        {
            GC = GameObject.Find(Hit.collider.gameObject.name);
            GC.renderer.material.color = Color.red ;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I click on other object the Previous objects become blue, so I know which objects are selected from the start of application.
Then I create a line between two last objects and show the distance.
Any help about how create the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var CP = new GameOject ; // current selected
var GCP = new GameOject ; // previous selected
public static ObjectNames[] ={"current" , "previous"}; // change on select static to use these name elsewhere 
string pName =""; // save the previous object name
int x = 0; // track if only clicked once 


if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            Ray Raycost = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit Hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(Raycost , out Hit , 230.0f , mask_ ))
            {



                if(x != 0 && x < 2) // be sure selected at least 2 object
                {
                    GCP =GameObject.Find(Pname); // on one click it is not working Pname is "" but when we came back ..;
                    ObjectNames[0] = Pname;
                    GCP.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
                    x = 0;
                }

                x = 1 ;




                GC = GameObject.Find(Hit.collider.gameObject.name); // current selected
                GC.renderer.material.color = Color.red ;



                Pname = Hit.collider.gameObject.name; //pname = current it loop on next click
                ObjectNames[1] = Hit.collider.gameObject.name;

            }

        }
```

Hope this Work.

Comment: My bad in line 3 use--public static string[] ObjectNames = { "current", "previous" };